# Edit Crystal report file without Crystal Report software

Tags: crystal-reports

I need to modify a static text (few words) in 3 rpt files. But I dont have Crystal Reports. How can I do it?

Is there a free editor or software to be able to modify a simple text of the report?

Answer (score 24):

In case anyone else is looking for this... as of April 2013, you can still get the free Visual Studio edition of Crystal Reports from this web site: [SAP Crystal Reports - Downloads (updated url)](https://www.crystalreports.com/crystal-reports-visual-studio/).

It installs into Visual Studio 2010 or VS 2012, and you can edit and save RPT files with as much capability as the standard Crystal Reports editor.

Comment: Unfortunately it appears external redistribution of "server application" still requires a paid licence (one time though, not subscription-based). [Crystal Reports for VS2010 Licensing] (http://scn.sap.com/people/blair.wheadon/blog/2010/04/19/crystal-reports-for-visual-studio-2010-licensing)

Comment: The download link has moved to a product on their main page here: https://www.crystalreports.com/crystal-reports-visual-studio/

Comment: @user19702 Thanks! I've updated the link in the answer.

Comment: Update: CR for VS2022 and above... https://www.sap.com/registration/trial.9a4afb3b-7eaa-42af-98ce-abeae5deb784.html but via a free account login

Answer (score 6):

My dad moved his office after 30 year and they need to update the address in the header of their Crystal Reports 7 (1997!) based billing system.

After buying old copies of Access 97 and Visual Studio 2003 Pro, I found out that both programs were too new - they could open the RPT files, but they saved them with an updated version that would not open in the billing system.

I ended up being able to make the changes using this life-saver program...

http://www.softwareforces.com/Products/rpt-inspector-professional-suite-for-crystal-reports

It was available with a 10 day free trial, and I only needed about 10 minutes to make my changes. That said, I would have happily paid whatever they asked for it. :)

Some hints:

1. When I opened my RPT files, I got an error saving the database could not be found. I ignored this error and everything worked fine.
2. Because my RPT files were Crystal Reports version 7, I had to go into Options->Misc and tell the program to save in the old format...

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If this is something you are only going to need to do once, have you considered downloading a demo version of Crystal? There's a 30-day trial version available here:
http://www.developers.net/businessobjectsshowcase/view/3154

Of course, if you need to edit these files after the 30 day period is over, you would be better off buying Crystal.

Alternatively, if all you need to do is replace a few static literal words, have you tried doing a search and replace in a text editor? (Don't forget to save the original files somewhere safe first!)

Comment: +1 for suggesting the demo.  I suggested a hex editor earlier, but Yae said they couldn't find anything.  ***shrug***

Comment: But this report is "old". I believe that of 2002 or something like that. If I modify it with a current TRIAL version will not it give problems on having read it with the program?

 In the text Editor only  apperas numbers and symbols. I can not modify from Editor

Comment: @yae, if you modify a report from an old version of Crystal with a newer version, it should ask you if you want to update the report to the newer version when you save it - if you answer "no", it should still save the modified version in the old format. So no, this should not be an issue, as long as you save it in the correct format.

Comment: @yae, have you tried **searching** the file in the text editor for the words in question? Crystal normally saves literal strings as themselves, but tokenises everything else in a .rpt file, so it should be possible to find the words in question.

Comment: Yes. I have tried to search text in the file rpt (someone already suggested it and I answered that it was not working, but he eliminated the message). If I open the file only appears numbers and symbols, and if I search: 0 results. have you tried to open a file RPT with an editor? What editor you uses?

Comment: @yae, I have done previously with older versions of Crystal (version 8, in particular), but when I try the same with files created in a more recent version of Crystal (version 10) I cannot find text that I know is in the report. It seems that this solution is only viable with files created in old versions of Crystal.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't have thought so.

If you have Visual Studio you could edit them through that.  Some versions of Visual Studio has Crystal Reports shipped with them.

If not, you will have to find someone who has Crystal Reports and ask then nicely to amend them for you. Or buy Crystal Reports!

Comment: my visual studio versions does not include CR. I am using other reports suite. To buy CR for modifying 2 words?! With this money I have to change 20 softwares!!

Comment: Crystal Reports has released an add-on for Visual Studio 2012 to support it: http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-35074 (the first download link.)

Answer (score 2):

This may be a long shot, but Crystal Reports for **Eclipse** is free.  I'm not sure if it will work, but if all you need is to edit some static text, you could get that version of CR and get the job done.