# How to edit crystal report without visual studio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I am using Crystal Report 13 with Visual Studio 2015. I have downloaded SAP Crystal report for that and it is working fine. But the problem is that in client site no visual studio is installed. How can I modify my reports in client site? I have downloaded Crystal Report viewer by SAP but modification/edit is not possible. Is there any edit tool available so I can change my reports without using VS 2015?

Any help will be thankfully accepted.

Thanks

Partha

Comment: Why you want to edit crystal report in Client machine, why don't you edit in your machine and copy that file in Client machine.

Comment: The the requirement has come form client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With ***Crystal Reports Viewer*** you can only ***view*** reports, like the name already says.
To edit reports, the [full version of Crystal Reports](http://www.crystalreports.com/) or Visual Studio is required.

Related question: [Edit Crystal report file without Crystal Report software](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737169/edit-crystal-report-file-without-crystal-report-software)