# Unable to Edit crystal report on client machine.

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I have deployed my asp.net project through IIS on client machine. I have installed crystal report runtime to execute my project successfully. But I can't edit any report. When I tried to install crystal report developer version it's asking for visual studio. 
What edition I need to edit crystal report on client  machine ? Please help.
I am using visual studio 2010

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Edit Crystal report file without Crystal Report software](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737169/edit-crystal-report-file-without-crystal-report-software)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 no longer includes Crystal Reports in the bundle.

In Visual Studio 2010, to create a Crystal Reports project or Web site or to import existing projects or Web sites that were created by using older versions of Visual Studio or Crystal Reports, you must first install a version of Crystal Reports that is compatible with Visual Studio 2010.

As per my experience,
Visual Studio 2010 should be installed first.
You would need CRforVS_13_0.exe (and not msi) version for Visual Studio 2010.
(Also check prior 32/64 bit version too)
And then you can edit the report from your project.

Comment: @Yeshwant_Mudholkar Did you understand my question ?

Comment: @ShaiwalTripathi : Oops I got it. Very Sorry! I would edit it. But still the process to edit the crystal report on client machine is same.  
Also thanks for pointing out my mistake in understanding your question. I would be more alert now onwards.

Answer (score 0):

See: https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Crystal+Reports%2C+Developer+for+Visual+Studio+Downloads 
It provides links and instructions for downloading what you need.